# replace method with strings in python using loops

Tags: python, replace

I have the following code:

```
secretWord = 'hello'
letter = 'l'
tag = '_ '*len(secretWord) # tag = '_ _ _ _ _'

for m in rage(len(secretWord)):
    if letter == secretWord[m] and m == 0:
         tag.replace(tag[m],letter)
    else:
         tag.replace(tag[m+2],letter)
```

The desired out put i want is `tag = '_ _ l l _'`
for some reason i simply can't get this to work even though my logic is perfectly accurate. I have a for loop going over each character in secretWord, if letter is then equal to that specific character at that time in the for loop, replace appropriate position in tag with that letter and keep all other blanks(' _ ') the same.

Comment: replace doesn't modify in-place, it returns.  So `tag = tag.replace(...)`

Comment: Looking at this again, your problem is more that not reassigning tag with returned value of `tag.replace`.  You also are trying to replace a specific `_` using `tag[m]` or `tag[m+2]`, but that isn't going to do what you think it is. See @unutbu's answer.

Comment: you could also use a regex: `tag = ' '.join(re.sub('[^%s]' % letter, '_', secret_word))`

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable in Python, you cannot modify them. This is why your `tag` is not updated.

Python has a very strange, yet useful, data model. Some types are mutable (for example lists and dictionaries) and some are immutable (for example strings and numbers).

The `replace()` function of string instances (and actually all other string functions) cannot modify the string. Instead it returns a new modified version of the original string.

One of the bigger differences between python and unmanaged programming languages like C/C++ is that in python variables are always references to values while in C/C++ variables are the actual storage for values.

Strangely, when starting with python this can be ignored to a certain degree, because the syntax of certain algorithms is the same. Something like:

```
a = 7
a += 35
s = "Hello"
s += " World"
```

yields `a = 42` and `s = "Hello World"` in Python and C/C++. This is clear for C/C++, but in python something completely unobvious happens.

In python `s` first refers to the string `"Hello"` (not: `s` contains the string `"Hello"`). Then the string `Hello` and the string `World` get concatenated and then the reference `s` is reset to point to the new string `"Hello World"`.

The next thing is that `a = b` always means: Copy the reference. It will never copy the value. For strings and integers it does not make much difference in practice, but for more complex types it does. But this is probably exceeding this question now.

Comment: There is another problem with the OP's code, see my comment in question if you care to address it.

Answer (score 1):

Let `tag` be a list of the known or blank characters. 
Use `' '.join(tag)` to make the displayed form when you need it.

---

```
secretWord = 'hello'
letter = 'l'

tag = ['_']*len(secretWord)
tag = [(letter if m == letter else t) for m, t in zip(secretWord, tag)]

print(' '.join(tag))
# _ _ l l _
```

---

Here are some links which explain the tools used in this solution:

- `[expr for variable in iterable]` is a [list
  comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).
- `letter if m == letter else t` is a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).
- [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) was used to pair letters in the `secretWord` with letters in
  `tag`.
- [`' '.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is used to join the list of letters into a single
  string with a space in between each letter.

Comment: Comprehensive, concise and correct.  This even fixes some other issues with the OP's code.

Comment: @unutbu This is exactly what I needed, i'm new to python so i'm not used to the style exhibited in this post but agree it is the best i've seen. I also have to learn about the join method and the zip function. That's why i love SO.